# How To Determine Grades in Python

Tags: python

This is using Python 3, through a website known as Repl.it

I am currently working on solving a question that states:
"Write a program that will take a grade between 100 and 0 zero and print the letter grade according to the scale:
90 or above is equivalent to an A grade
80-89 is equivalent to a B grade
70-79 is equivalent to a C grade
65-69 is equivalent to a D grade
64 or below is equivalent to an F grade
if user gives something other then integer or something that is not between 0 and 100 give an error and ask again.
Example run:
Enter the number grade: asd
Program only accepts integers between 0 and 100
Enter the number grade: 65
Your grade is D"

My current code is as follows:

```
def printgrade(score):
  if score >= 90:
    print("A")
  elif score >= 80:
    print("B")
  elif score >= 70:
    print("C")
  elif score >= 65:
    print("D")
  elif score <= 64:
    print("F")
  else:
    print("ERROR")

def main():
  score = int(input("Enter a score: "))
  print("Your grade is:", printgrade(score))

main()
```

The only error message that I am receiving is that print is invalid syntax, but I cannot figure out as to why, am I just missing something? Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `score = (input("Enter a score: ")` This is an invalid syntax because of the `(` before the `input`. Also since user input is of type `str`, you should convert it to `int`. So use, `score = int(input("Enter a score: "))`

Comment: Also take a look at your testing statements. Four of them are true in the case that your entered grade is greater than or equal to 65. Your order eliminates the false positives, but you should be a little more direct.

Comment: which python version are you on?

Comment: You are going to want to `return 'A'` to avoid the double `print` statement and printing `None`

Comment: One of the tests says: "Enter the number grade: asd Program only accepts integers between 0 and 100" So your program needs to detect non-numeric input and display that error message.

Comment: The code in your question does not throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the error with the `(` going through the code some modifications could make this a little more optimal.  We can use a `try, except` block to eliminate the `ERROR` else statement and handle that directly when we receive the `input` if is not a valid `int` and we force a valid `int` between `0 and 100` using a while statement.  Next our function should `return 'A'` or `B, C` etc. Then when we can use the `print('Your grade is: ', printgrade(score))` as desired

```
def printgrade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 65:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

def main():
    score = ''
    while score not in range(0,101):
        try:
            score = int(input("Enter a score: "))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid Entry')
    print("Your grade is:", printgrade(score))

main()
```

Comment: This solved my syntax errors, the only adjustment I had to make was to instead print "This program only accepts integers between 0 and 100" instead of "invalid entry".

Comment: @MarissaPage Glad to help! best of luck , cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def printgrade(score): 
  if score >= 90: return "A"
  elif score >= 80: return "B"
  elif score >= 70: return "C"
  elif score >= 65: return "D"
  elif score <= 64: return "F"
  else: return "ERROR"

def main(): 
  score = int(input("Enter a score: "))     
  print("Your grade is:", printgrade(score))

main()
```

Hope it helps. You have to return value and not print them inside the sub function as your print function is expecting a value from your sub function.

Comment: When will your code return `"ERROR"` ? And what happens if the user enters `asd`?